# How to read a env variable added in script execution from GitHub workflow

Tags: python, github, github-actions

Execute a script (tmp.py) with workflow that has below line:

```
os.environ["VERSION"] = "Version 1.1.1.2.2.3"
print(os.system('env')) #prints all env included above one
```

Now I need this var in workflow:

```
- name: Run script
        run: python3 tmp.py

- name: print env var
  if: always()
  run: |
    echo ${{ env.VERSION  }} #Blank, expected the value "Version 1.1.1.2.2.3"
```

It prints blank. Later I have gone through the GitHub docs and found that this syntax {{ env.APP_VERSION  }} can be used only if env itself added in workflow.

So how can I use this var os.environ["VERSION"] value in workflow ?

Document link: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables
I have not tried **Job.<job_id>.env** as it seems related to  JOB env.

Answer (score 0):

To save an environment variable in a step (to use it in another one), you would generally use the following syntax:

```
echo "foo=bar" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

In a Python script, that would be done similarly. I'm personally using the following syntax which directly write the variable to the env file:

```
import os

env_file = os.getenv('GITHUB_ENV')

bar='bar'

with open(env_file, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(f"foo={bar}")
```

The variable could then be accessed in a following step by using `${{ env.foo }}`.

*Note that this solution works for outputs by using `GITHUB_OUTPUT` instead of `GITHUB_ENV`.*

Comment: I have used python one and it worked. Thanks!!